# Keycloak: How to determine hostname from within an eventlistener

Tags: keycloak

I want to register my keycloak instance with a service. I have implemented an eventlistener and want to determine the hostname at startup (in the init() or postInit() method). At this point I have no session and if I create a session, this session has no valid context. If I had some, I could obtain it from `keycloakSession.getContext().getUri()`,
Does anybody know how to get the hostname?